# How to create a wifi hotspot using wifi connection

Tags: networking, hot-spot

I am very new to ubuntu . I am using ubuntu 14.04.01 and i am  using a wifi connection and i don't have a lan connection. I want to create a wifi hotspot using this connection. I searched on sites but i only get the methods to create it with lan.

I tried http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/wifi-hotspot-ubuntu-laptop-android/

thanks in advance.

Comment: Which connection do you want hotspot to be created from?

Comment: @Raphael i want hotspot to be created from wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and click on Network

[image: Go to Settings]

Now click on Wireless(if not already selected) and then click on "Use as Hotspot"(below list of available networks)

[image: Click on wireless]

[image: Click on use as Hotspot]

Click on turn on (It may ask for name, password, encryption type etc. if you haven't ever used it.)

[image: Hotspot menu]

This method works for me...

Comment: i want to use my wifi connection to use hotspot . I already used it , it will ask you for lan. It will not jump my wifi connection.